# What is the significance of amritaghateshwara temple?

Tags: shiva, history, temple, devi

The.famous temple of abirami (goddess)-amrita ghateshwara (shiva) at Tirukkadiyur has an interesting fact that it also contains Lord Vishnu temple alongside. It has many miraculous and special stories associated to it.

What are the legends and beliefs associated with the temple?

What is the history and story of this temple?